# Why can't I return a shared pointer in C++14 when the function return type is bool?

Tags: c++, return, return-value, smart-pointers, boolean-expression

I'm using g++ and write a simple function:

```
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<char> ptr;

bool fails_compiling()
{
    return ptr;
}
```

From what I can see in the interface, the `shared_ptr` implementation includes a `bool` operator and I can even apply a quick fix like this:

```
    return static_cast<bool>(ptr);
```

And it now compiles.

Why would the return algorithm not attempt an auto-conversion to `bool` like the `if()` and `while()` do?

Comment: The bool operator is `explicit`.

Comment: That bool operator is for backward compatibility with lousy style. Better compare for inequality with `nullptr` that is required to be equal with cast to bool like `return ptr != nullptr;`.

Comment: @ÖöTiib, in which official document does it say that's "backward compatibility"?

Comment: Why to write obvious truisms into documents? That the `ptr` is useful as `ptr != nullptr` is obviously inherited from C. That the `shared_ptr::operator bool` is made `explicit` is obviously for to narrow down its usages into limited contexts. B. Stroustrup has mentioned type safety as intention countless times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you checkout [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool)'s bool conversion operator, you will see that it's declared as:

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

The use of `explicit` simply tells the compiler to forbid [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), which is what would have taken place because the return type of your function is different from the object type you are returning. However, this doesn't affect [*contextual conversions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions).

which occurs in the context of any:

> - controlling expression of `if`, `while`, `for`;
> - the logical operators `!`, `&&` and `||`;
> - the conditional operator `?:`;
> - `static_assert`;
> - `noexcept`.

*above quote cited from cppreference*

Comment: So in other words they have a few special cases for the `bool` type, which does not include the `return` statement.

Comment: Yes, something like that. I will say the only place `explicit` is not *totally* respected in the sense of being `explicit` is in `bool` conversion operator. And as you can see, its only to a very specific and limited context, which makes sense....

Answer (score 2):

> Why would the return algorithm not attempt an auto-conversion to `bool` like the `if()` and `while()` do?

[std::shared_ptr::operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool) is `explicit` conversion function, so implicit conversion is not allowed, but `static_cast` (explicit conversion) works well.

When used for `if` or `while`, [contextual conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions) takes effect, then the explicit user-defined conversion function will be considered. In this case, `std::shared_ptr` is *contextually convertible to `bool`*.

> In the following five contexts, the type `bool` is expected and the implicit conversion sequence is built if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed. that is, the explicit user-defined conversion function such as `explicit T::operator bool() const;` is considered. Such expression e is said to be *contextually convertible to bool*.
>
> - controlling expression of if, while, for;
> - the logical operators !, && and ||;
> - the conditional operator ?:;
> - static_assert;
> - noexcept.

Answer (score 2):

### Why the code doesn't compile.

`std::shared_ptr`'s conversion-to-`bool` operator is declared `explicit` and so will generally not be invoked for an implicit conversion.

In particular it will not be invoked in the context of a `return` statement.

And it will not be considered for choosing a function overload, i.e. `foo(p)` will not resolve to an overload of `foo` that takes a `bool` argument.

There are however umpteen ways to express the conversion explicitly, including:

```
!!ptr

ptr != nullptr

ptr.get() != nullptr

static_cast<bool>( ptr )

ptr.operator bool()
```

---

### The general case for implicit conversion to `bool`.

There are some cases where `explicit` on an `operator bool()` is *ignored*, in order to make things work mainly as in C++03. That is, to make things work as with the schemes employed before `explicit` was allowed on conversion operators in C++11. These exceptions are

- use as a (grammar production) *condition* in an `if`, `while` or `for`, but not in a `switch`,
- use as condition in `:?` choice, `static_assert` or `noexcept`,
- use as argument to the built-in boolean operators `&&`, `||` and `!`, or their equivalents `and`, `or` and `not`.

Notably, again, these exceptions that allow implicit conversion to `bool` in spite of `explicit`, known as **contextual conversions**, do not include a `return` statement expression.

---

### Can `explicit` be ignored also in other cases?

In what other cases, if any, can `explicit` on a conversion operator be ignored?

Well, none. But a non-`explicit` conversion operator, that is, an implicit conversion operator, can be invoked implicitly where the exact type to be converted to is not specified by the context.

*C++11 §4/5 (conv):*

> **”** Certain language constructs require conversion to a value having one of a specified set of types appropriate
>   to the construct. An expression `e` of class type `E` appearing in such a context is said to be ***contextually implicitly converted*** to a specified type `T` and is well-formed if and only if `e` can be implicitly converted to
>   a type `T` that is determined as follows: `E` is searched for conversion functions whose return type is *cv* `T` or reference to *cv* `T` such that `T` is allowed by the context. There shall be exactly one such `T`.

For example,

*C++11 §5.3.5/1 (expr.delete):*

> **”**  If of class type, the operand [of `delete`] is contextually
>   implicitly converted (Clause 4) to a pointer to object type.

… and so, a bit counter-intuitive to me!, the following should compile with a conforming compiler:

```
struct Foo
{
    operator int*() const { return nullptr; }
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    delete Foo();
}
```